# Checkers in Python 3

Tags: python, game, python-3.x

I'm writing a small checkers game in python (international rules) and I need some pointers here and there. For the moment, I am only drawing the board and checking the syntax of moves with a regex.

**For review**:

- Usage of a value package for passing around game state (grid, turn_count, and current player), is there a better way, or is this acceptable?
- I have some issue with `GRID_HEIGHT` and `GRID_WIDTH`. As they are constants and supposed to be reflecting the size of my grid, I know it is bad to let them hardcoded to 10 that way. However, as far as I can tell, I can't set their values after generating the grid. I guess I should compute them and put them in the value package.
- As for `transform_response_into_tuples(response)`, I would like to find a neater way to make the tuples (I should say the pairs). I mean it's working but I think it is ugly.
- Also, the printing is quite rigid, note the use of empty print statement in order to line break.
- Finally, is there some statement that could be made more "pythonic"?

Here is how looks:

[image: How it looks]

```
#CONSTANTS SECTION
CLEAR = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
GRID_HEIGHT = 10
GRID_WIDTH = 10
#White pawn
WP = "▓"
#White queen
WQ = '£'
#Empty cell
EC = ' '
#Black pawn
BP = '░'
#Black Queen
BQ = '$'
#players
PLAYERS = Enum("Players", "White Black")
#END OF CONSTANTS SECTION

def init_grid():
    """Initialize the new game grid"""
    grid = [[EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP],
            [BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC],
            [EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP],
            [BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC, BP, EC],
            [EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC],
            [EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC, EC],
            [EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP],
            [WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC],
            [EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP],
            [WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC, WP, EC]]
    return grid

def move(value_package):
    """This function moves the pieces according to the player's wish"""
    print("Turn : ", value_package["turn_count"])
    if value_package["cur_turn"] == PLAYERS.White:
        print("White's turn :\n")
        print_board(value_package["board"])
        #Ask for command until the syntax is correct
        while True:
            print("Enter movement :", end="")
            if interpret_response(value_package["board"], input()) == True:
                value_package["cur_turn"] = PLAYERS.Black
                value_package["turn_count"] += 1
                break
    else:
        print("Black's turn :\n")
        #print_board(value_package["board"])
        #DO THE AI ACTION
        value_package["cur_turn"] = PLAYERS.White
        #value_package["turn_count"] += 1

def interpret_response(board, response):
    """This functon interprets the response"""
    if check_response_syntax(response):
        tuples = transform_response_into_tuples(response)
        if check_move_legality(board, tuples):
            return True
    else:
        print("Syntax Error")
    return False

def check_response_syntax(response):
    """This function checks if the syntax of the response is correct"""
    #Example of correct syntax: 7A6B OR 9F9F (Which is not a legal move !)
    return False if re.match("^([0-9][A-J]){2}$", response) == None else True

def transform_response_into_tuples(response):
    """This function decompose the response into tuples"""
    match = re.findall("([0-9][A-J]){1}", response)
    # -65 because ASCII A-Z to integers (remember A == 0 ...)
    # -48 because ASCII 1-9 to integers (remember 0 == 0 ...)
    l_val1 = ord(match[0][0]) - 48
    r_val1 = ord(match[0][1]) - 65
    l_val2 = ord(match[1][0]) - 48
    r_val2 = ord(match[1][1]) - 65
    return ((l_val1, r_val1), (l_val2, r_val2))

def check_move_legality(board, tuples):
    """This function checks if the move is legal"""
    return True

def print_board(board):
    """This function is drawing the board"""
    print("      A B C D E F G H I J\n")
    for i in range(GRID_HEIGHT):
        print(i, "   |", end="")
        for j in range(GRID_WIDTH):
            current_cell = board[i][j]
            print(current_cell + "|", end="")
        print("")
    print("")

def main():
    """ Entry point """
    CLEAR()
    print("PY-CHECKERS")
    value_package = dict([("board", init_grid()), ("turn_count", 1), ("cur_turn", PLAYERS.White)])
    while True:
        move(value_package)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 6):

- The

  ```
  def check_move_legality(board, tuples):
      """This function checks if the move is legal"""
      return True
  ```

  puts the code on the verge of being off-topic.
- The `from` and `to` fields is not enough to uniquely identify the move: there could be two multiple captures following different paths.
- In logical context `None` evaluates to `False`. You may

  ```
      return re.match("^([0-9][A-J]){2}$", response)
  ```

  directly. In fact, `return False if condition else True` is considered an anti-pattern.

  Also I recommend to parse the response directly: syntax validation is a side effect of successful parsing.
- Docstrings are not very informative.

  It doesn't tell me much that `This function decompose the response into tuples`. Consider something along the lines of `Parse response into start and end fields`. If the function has a side effect (such as ultimate change of a board state) it must be in docstring as well.

Comment: I agree with you on most of the points. 

However, I don't really see why parsing the response directly is better than checking it before, then parsing only if the string is right.

Sticking with the actual code, I would need to add new checks when parsing.

eg : `if len(match) != 2: return False`
 
So it may be better for speed to do it this way (I reckon regexes are pretty slow),  but I think it impairs readability.

Anyway, fot the current code, this implies that nobody should ever give a syntacticly incorrect string to `transform_response_into_tuples` which may be wrong too.

Comment: *"puts the code on the verge of being off-topic."* The original question explained what parts of the code had been done, so this isn't really in the realm of nonworking code.